# Function not working in chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript

When I'm testing my code in the browser everything works fine and text from the clip is being pasted inside search box but when I load the code to chrome function doesn't work . Any idea why lack of permission?

```js
document.querySelector('.pasteBtn').addEventListener('click', pasteFromClip);

function pasteFromClip(){
    result = navigator.clipboard.readText().then(
    clipText => document.getElementById('Search').value = clipText);
  console.log('Clicked')
}
```

```html
<input id ="Search" type="text" name="Search" value = '' placeholder="search..."><br>
<input type="button" value="From Clip" class="pasteBtn">
```

Comment: this might be an issue with your one liners and non braces approach can you please try by adding callback necessary braces

Comment: Error message in the background script console? You don't say which context this script is running in - background script? Content script? Popup?

Comment: A script running in popup no errors besides log in console "Clicked".

Comment: Looks like problem lays in part of the core which is getting text from clipboard when I'm leaving only code below it works fine 

`document.getElementById('Search').value = 'test'`